# Find a date range from a date

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-range

How would you solve the problem below?

On a given date, I'd like to find the range of an academic year. The academic years always start on the first of September and lasts until the last of August. Thus, for today (2015-07-16) I would like the function return the dates 2014-09-01 and 2015-08-31. If I were to run the same function in three months (2015-10-16) I'd like to get 2015-09-01 and 2016-08-31 returned.

Thank you,

/Thomas

-- edit requested by @anant-kumar-singh --

An example function in PHP:

```
function getAcademicYear($date) {
    // Logic code...
    return array($dateStart, $dateEnd);
}
```

Calling `getAcademicYear('2015-07-16');` should return the array, `['2014-09-01','2015-08-31']`

And calling `getAcademicYear('2015-10-16');`
should return the array, `['2015-09-01','2016-08-31']`

-- edit --

```
function findAcademicYear($date) {
    $dateTime = new DateTime($date);
    $dateTime->sub(new DateInterval("P8M"));
    return(array(
        "startDate" => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateTime->format("Y")."-08-31 + 1 day")),
        "endDate" => ($dateTime->format("Y") + 1)."-08-31")
        );
}
```

Comment: you are able to understand your question but we not. elaborate by giving some example and expected outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following logic:  Subtract 8 months from the date, extract the year, and use that for the specification of the year:

```
select date(concat(year(date_sub(date, interval 8 month)), '-09-01')) as academic_start,
       date(concat(1 + year(date_sub(date, interval 8 month)), '-08-31')) as academic_end
```

Comment: Good idea @GordonLinoff, though if the date is in September the result will be 1 year off (2015-09-16 returns academic_start: 2014-09-01, academic_end: 2015-08-31 instead of academic_start: 2015-09-01, academic_end: 2016-08-31). I'll create the function in PHP when everything works.

Comment: @Thomas to be correct you must subtract 8 months, not 9

Comment: Thanks, accepted as solution! - I appended the PHP function in my question.